# 12 V pulse circuit to operate a double coil latching relay uses no power unless switching

Tags: relay, dc, latching-relay

[image: Latching Relay specs]

I have a double coil latching relay and I need a circuit that will provide a pulse to switch it on. After the pulse I don't want it to use any power.

There are two sides to the circuit, one to turn the latching relay on, and another to turn it off.

I'm using the latching relay as a high-voltage disconnect for a 12 V LiFePO4 battery.

My BMS has a small 1 A, 12 V relay with NO and NC which will provide the power to the pulse circuit that would latch and unlatch the relay.

[image]

Comment: It will cost you about a quarter-Joule per relay state change. No escaping that. That discounts inefficiencies. So you should plan on more. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pulse generator schematic.

[image]

(1NO + 2NC) contacts would be required from the BMS relay K1.

Answer (score 0):

> My BMS

DO NOT USE A LATCHING RELAY with a BMS!

Latching relays / contactors are not fail safe.

You MUST use a regular relay, contactor, solid state relay, or MOSFET. Anything that goes off when the power goes away.

(I am in the business, and I've had more than one customer who killed their Li-ion battery by using a latching relay.)

The problem is that, if something goes wrong with the system (a loose connection, a broken wire, no power to the BMS, the microcontroller resets, etc.) the latching contactor remains on, when it should be turned off.

If you need low stand-by power, switch to a protector BMS with MOSFETs. They now make BMSs for 48 V for up to 300 A.